# Swift 2 syntax error with direction .Forward

Tags: ios, swift, syntax-error, swift2

I wrote in Swift 1.2 the next:

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but now, in Swift 2 it prints me the next error:

```
Could not find member 'Forward'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward instead of .Forward?

Comment: in this case it prints `animated: true`  part the next error `'Bool' is not convertible to 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'`

Comment: The error is probably in the first argument which should have type `[UIViewController]?`. Try to just remove the `as [AnyObject]` (depends on how viewControllers is declared).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should make sure that your viewControllers not optional Type. Such as:

```
var viewControllers:[UIViewController] = [VC1,VC2]
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```